# How many vectors are there in the basis of solution set for Ax=0?

Tags: linear-algebra

How many vectors are there in the basis of a solution set for $Ax=0$ if
$$
A = 
\left(\begin{array}{cc} 
4 & 5 & 7 & -3 & 1\\
11 & 8 & -4 & 2 & 0
\end{array}\right)
$$
I know the answer is 3 (it's a problem from a MOOC) but I don't fully understand how to get the result. My guess is: since rows of $A$ are linearly independent, the system will have the solution in the form like this:
$$
x = 
\left(\begin{array}{cc} 
a_{01} \\
a_{02} \\
a_{03} \\
a_{04} \\
a_{05}
\end{array}\right)
+ x_3 * 
\left(\begin{array}{cc} 
a_{31} \\
a_{32} \\
a_{33} \\
a_{34} \\
a_{35}
\end{array}\right)
+ x_4 * 
\left(\begin{array}{cc} 
a_{41} \\
a_{42} \\
a_{43} \\
a_{44} \\
a_{45}
\end{array}\right)
+ x_5 * 
\left(\begin{array}{cc} 
a_{51} \\
a_{52} \\
a_{53} \\
a_{54} \\
a_{55}
\end{array}\right)
$$
$a_{ij}$ is some number. The first vector is a partial solution, and three other vectors form a homogeneous solution and they are the basis of a solution set. So in short, the answer for this type of problem is `a number of columns in A minus rank(A)`. Am I correct?

Comment: The nullity of an $m$ by $n$ vector is $n-rank$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are correct about using the Rank & Nullity theorem. Observe that $A$ has rank of $2$ because the rows of $A$ are linearly independent because the second row is not a multiple of the first row. And this shows that the dimension of the null space of $A$ is $3$. Alternatively, you can row reduce $A$ in RREF and the number of free variables equals to the nullity of $A$ which is $3$ in this example.

Answer (score 0):

The rank of a matrix is also the number of linearly independent columns. The two last columns are independent vectors of $\mathbb{R}^2$, and so rank(A) is 2. Then the nulity of A is 5-2=3.